# cronjob bash script called within another shell script not working

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a shell script which calls a bash script within it. when I run this shell script manually it works fine however when I schedule this thru cronjob, the bash script is not doing the intended job.

shell script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

SHDIR=/oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst

export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME SHDIR TIMESTMP DATESTAMP

cd $SHDIR

TO=<actual email address>
BCC=<actual email address>

if [ -f /oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst/SCTempConst.xlsx ]
then
SUBJECT="Subject ...."

ATTCH=SCTempConst.xlsx

export TO BCC SUBJECT ATTCH SHDIR
./BNSendMail.sh

fi
```

the BNSendmail is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ${SHDIR}
FROM="<from email id>"

boundary="ZZ_/afg6432dfgkl.94531q"
body=`cat msg.txt`

# Build headers
{

printf '%s\n' "From: $FROM
To: $TO
Cc: $CC
Bcc: $BCC
Subject: $SUBJECT
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--${boundary}
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

$body
"

mimetype1=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}
Content-Type: $mimetype1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"${ATTCH}\"
"

base64 "${SHDIR}/${ATTCH}"
echo

# print last boundary with closing --
printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}--"

} | sendmail -t -oi
```

As I said this is working perfectly fine when execute manually.
only when I set this as a cronjob, its not emailing.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
basu

Comment: what is you cron entry for this ? in cron you can set SHELL var to be executed within specific shell

Comment: May or may not be related: `#!/usr/bin/sh` isn't likely to be a valid shebang.

Comment: Did you try adding the full path instead of running as ./ ?

Comment: my crontab entry is as follows:

Comment: 00 05 * * * /export/home/oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst/SCTempConst_Mail.

Comment: I meant within the main script you are invoking ./BNSendMail.sh . Can you try invoking as /oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst/BNSendMail.sh ? When you say it's not working, do you see any errors?

Comment: i tired even /export/home/oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst/SCTempConst_Mail.sh and it does not do anything. there are no errors written anywhere. how do i check for error when it runs frm cronjob?

Comment: You have the line `export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME SHDIR TIMESTMP DATESTAMP` in your script but they're not set anywhere in the script; hence the export is useless. If the working of the script(s) depend on those, then you need to set those explicitly when running from `cron`. Presumably they're set in your `.profile` or similar when you log in.

Comment: sorry of those exports only SHDIR is relevant and it is set.

Comment: @BasuNavindgi: You could add some logging/debugging in your script to see where it fails. Also, you ran the main wrapper with the full path, I'm talking about adding the full path in BNSendMail.sh. Instead of invoking it as "./", can you invoke with the full path - /oracle/CMC/scripts/utils/SCTempConst/BNSendMail.sh ?

Comment: hi Rahul, yes i did change that line./BNSendMail.sh with full path name. but to no avail. also added some debug messages and it all looks ok until the build headers section..after that i don't know how to added anymore messages as they don't get executed

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. it was not finding `sendmail` when executed through `cron`, I had to specify the full path of `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and it worked!